# Fullcalendar displaying Month and year weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using Fullcalendar but when ever I switch to "week view" and then use the forward and back buttons the date is displaying really weird, like so... How can I fix this and/or has anyone had this issue?

```
 Jun 4 â€“ 10, 2017
```

This is my code:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left:   'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right:  'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    buttonText: {
        today: 'today',
        month: 'month',
        week:  'week',
        day:   'day'
    },
    eventDurationEditable: false
)};
```

Comment: can you make a snippet that reproduces it? Looks like probably a UTF encoding issue. check whether the encoding of your page is UTF-8 or not, and maybe try on another browser and device as well.

Comment: I just decided to scrap the feature all together.

Comment: you shouldn't need to, it works well normally. You can see examples of it on the fullCalendar website working fine. Did you try and investigate the encoding?